# Validate User Input during installation using VS Installer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-installer, custom-action

I am creating an msi using VS installer but I've run into a problem. What I need to do is take input from the user, a server name/port and username/passsword. Once I have this I need to verify that they are correct then continue with the installation r return to the input page. 
I've tried using Windows Forms Project as a Custom Action but I have to use static linking for this msi so that is not possible. 
I have the code written (c++) to validate all the credentials I just need a way to revert back to the input screen if they are incorrect. 
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Greetings,
KB

Comment: you want to catch this info's from the setup screen ?

Comment: yes, for example, when installing a microsoft software you input the license key this then checks the license, continues if its accepted or returns to the "input license" screen. This is exactly what I need to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to make sure that your custom action can receive the installation handle: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx

After that, configure your custom action to set an installer property based on the validation result. This property can then be used to control the dialog. Perhaps this will help:
http://setupanddeployment.com/installation-user-interface/validate-user-input-installation/

What you need to do requires access to [control events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so it's not really doable in a Visual Studio setup project. You can try using a different setup authoring tool which offers more control over the installation UI:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I decided to use InstallShield and this makes it much easier!